# Extjs And Grails How can i prevent ancestors

Tags: javascript, grails, extjs4.1

I work a project which server site is Grails, Client Site is Extjs4.1, I use relational database. In this situation i work fine but when i call store then i facing some problem.
This problem based on parents. when I call store like below..... then i must call its parents but i do not want to call its parents..

```
def stote(){        
    def prices = []
    Price.getAll()?.each{ v ->
        def a = v.article,
        b     = a.brand,
        bt    = b.brandType,
        gp    = b.genericProducts,
        c     = gp.categories,
        m     = b.manufacturers

        def manufacture     = [id:m.id,     name:m.name]
        def category        = [id:c.id,     name:c.name]
        def genericProduct  = [id:gp.id,    name:gp.name, m01i001001:category]
        def brandType       = [id:bt.id,    name:bt.name]
        def brand           = [id:b.id, name:b.name, m01i002001:manufacture, m01i003001:genericProduct, m01i004001:brandType]
        def article         = [id:a.id, name:a.name, mbcode:a.mbcode, pbcode:a.pbcode, details:a.details, m01i005001:brand]
        def price           = [id: v.id, m01i006001:article, price:v.price, date:v.date]
        prices << price
    }
    return prices
}
```

Those are belongTo association key
m01i001001, m01i002001, m01i003001,m01i004001,m01i005001,m01i006001

my belongTo like as

```
 belongsTo : [{
  model          : '${pkgName}.M01I005001',
  associatedName : 'M01I005001' ,
  associationKey : 'm01i005001' , 
  primaryKey     : 'id' , 
  foreignKey     : 'brandId'     
}],
```

i want to call like this store...

```
def stote(){        
    def prices = []
    Price.getAll()?.each{ v ->
        def a = v.article

        def article         = [id:a.id, name:a.name, mbcode:a.mbcode, pbcode:a.pbcode, details:a.details]
        def price           = [id: v.id, m01i006001:article, price:v.price, date:v.date]
        prices << price
    }
    return prices
}
```

but when i call this store then client side loading problem. I can not lazy its parents. its show always eager.

Please let me know if you have any idea to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution for this. I create a proxy model for this and i remove all relation which are not necessary then i solve my problem that means i keep only one belongsto so keep only one association key.